# Pandas value_counts using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
    A   B   key1    key2
0   A0  B0  K0  K0
1   A1  B1  K0  K1
2   A2  B2  K1  K0
3   A3  B3  K2  K1
4   A0  B0  K0  K0
```

I know that I can get the counts of unique values in the 'key1' column with this: `df['key1'].value_counts()` which returns something like this:

```
K0    3
K1    1
K2    1
```

But what if I want to get counts of combinations between the two key columns. To return something like this:

```
K0  K0    2
K0  K1    1
K0  K1    1
K0  K1    1
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['key1', 'key2']).size()`

Comment: @user3483203 Perfect, that works, thanks.